# Calling a static variable

Tags: c#, .net, variables, static

Very simple and straight forward. I created 2 classes:
The first class. In this i declared a static variable so as to be able to access it in the other class without initialization.

```
protected class TCHome
{
   protected static String write = "blablabla";
}
```

the second class:

```
public class Home
{
   TCHome.write - //write does not come up to be accessible at all.;
}
```

What I'd expected is that I should be able to make a direct call to the variable - "write" but it does not come up at all. What's the right way? Please.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a.aspx

"A protected member of a base class is accessible in a derived class only if the access occurs through the derived class type."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`protected` means the type or member can be accessed only by code in the same class or struct, or in a class that is derived from that class.

You should make it `public` or `internal`.

> - **public**: The type or member can be accessed by any other code in the
>     same assembly or another assembly that references it.
> - **private**: The type
>     or member can be accessed only by code in the same class or struct.
> - **protected**: The type or member can be accessed only by code in the same
>     class or struct, or in a class that is derived from that class.
> - **internal**: The type or member can be accessed by any code in the same
>     assembly, but not from another assembly.
> - **protected internal**: The type or member can be accessed by any code in
>     the assembly in which it is declared, or from within a derived class
>     in another assembly. Access from another assembly must take place
>     within a class declaration that derives from the class in which the
>     protected internal element is declared, and it must take place through
>     an instance of the derived class type.

[reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx)

Also consider using **constants** if it suits your needs.

```
protected class TCHome
{
   public const string Write = "blablabla";
}
```

or make it a property, having public accessible fields is not a good approach.

```
protected class TCHome
{
   public static string Write { get; set; } //maybe private set;

   static { Write = "blablabla"; } //this is called static constructor
 }
```

or a readonly string

```
protected class TCHome
{
   public static readonly string Write = "blablabla";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The access modifier should be public, like below

```
public class TCHome
{
   public static String write = "blablabla";
}
```

Comment: there is no need to make the whole class public.

Answer (score 2):

You have put protected to the write, there must be subclass.

use `public`:

```
public static String write = "blablabla";
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be using **public** or **internal** access specifier as per your requirement

```
protected class TCHome
{
   public static String write = "blablabla";
}
```

OR

```
protected class TCHome
{
   internal static String write = "blablabla";
}
```

Comment: @dotctor Only the developer can determine which access specifier suits the current situation. Inside your project `internal` will also work. But if you're making a dll to be used in other projects then it has to be `public`.

Comment: the solution to make a class member or method visible outside of the class is not making it `public` always.

Answer (score 2):

`Protected` modifier is orthogonal to `static`. In other words, these are independent concepts, so there is no reason why you could access a `protected` method or variable from a class that is not derived.

To access `write` member from `Home` it should be public:

```
protected class TCHome
{
       public static String write = "blablabla";
}


public class Home
{
   TCHome.write - //write does not come up to be accessible at all.;
}
```

Here an overview of the access modifiers in C#:

> Access modifiers are specified as part of the method declaration
>   syntax and can be:
>
> ```
> internal
> private
> protected
> protected internal
> public
> ```
>
> If no modifier is specified, the method is given **private** access.
>
> **virtual** methods can be overriden by a derived class using the override
>   keyword.
>
> **abstract** methods must be overriden in a derived class. If any method
>   of a class is abstract, the entire class must be declared as abstract.
>
> **sealed** methods are methods that override an inherited virtual method
>   having the same signature. When a method is sealed, it cannot be
>   overriden in a derived class. Method Access Modifiers
>
> **public** indicates the method is freely accessible inside and outside of
>   the class in which it is defined.
>
> **internal** means the method is only accessible to types defined in the
>   same assembly.
>
> **protected** means the method is accessible in the type in which it is
>   defined, and in derived types of that type. This is used to give
>   derived classes access to the methods in their base class.
>
> **protected internal** means the method is accessible to types defined in
>   the same assembly or to types in a derived assembly.
>
> **private** methods are only accessible in the class in which they are
>   defined.

Source: http://blog.crsw.com/c-class-and-method-modifiers-overiew/

Answer (score 2):

Inherit tchome in home class. or change tchome from protected to public.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

either make your variable public (which is not recommended as public fields are bad, better make property or readonly field) or let your class `Home` derive from `TCHome`.

```
public class Home : TCHome {
    Home() {TCHome.write = /* ... */ }

}
```